# cross-process locking in linux

Tags: linux, mutex

I am looking to make an application in Linux, where only one instance of the application can run at a time.  I want to make it robust, such that if an instance of the app crashes, that it won't block all the other instances indefinitely.   I would really appreciate some example code on how to do this (as there's lots of discussion on this topic on the web, but I couldn't find anything which worked when I tried it).

Comment: What language? So far I recommend writing it in Erlang, so, you wouldn't have to worry at all. ;) If you wnat only one instance to run at a time, how come if it crashes it might block other instances?

Comment: If there can only be one instance at a time, then when it crashes there aren't any other instances running that it can block. Am I reading the question incorrectly?

Comment: The application reads a file, modifies it, then writes it back.  This is not concurrently safe if there are two instances running at the same time.  Also, I'm worried that if an instance starts, grabs the lock, then crashes before releasing the lock, then I don't want the next instance to get blocked (whether it starts afterwards, or is already waiting for the lock to be released)

Comment: The application is written in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use file locking facilities that Linux provides. You haven't specified the language, however you might find this capability pretty much everywhere in some form or another.

Here is a simple idea how to do that in a C program. When the program starts you can take an exclusive non-blocking lock on the whole file using `fcntl` system call. When another instance of the applications is attempted to be started, it will get an error trying to lock the file, which will mean the application is already running.

Here is a small example how to take the full file lock using `fcntl` (this function provides facilities for putting byte range locks, but when length is 0, the full file is locked).

```
   struct flock lock_struct;

   memset(&lock_struct, 0, sizeof(lock_struct));

   lock_struct.l_type = F_WRLCK;
   lock_struct.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
   lock_struct.l_pid = getpid();

   ret = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock_struct);
```

Please note that you need to open a file first to put a lock. This means you need to have a file around to use for locking. It might be useful to put the it somewhere where it won't cause any distraction/confusion for other applications.

When the process terminates, all locks that it has taken will be released, so nothing will be blocked.

This is just one of the ideas. I'm pretty sure there are other ways around.

Comment: So in the above example, fd is a file descriptor, which is opened previous to that.  My issue is that fcntl does not seem to be blocking.  I could put a loop around the fcntl call `while (!ret)`, and add a sleep in there.  While workable for my particular case, I was hoping for something more elagant like an actual cross-process-mutex of some sort.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a blocking lock for your case, but this can be achieved replacing `F_SETLK` with `F_SETLKW`.

Comment: If two people try to start the application simultaneously, I want both instances to run -- just not at the same time.

Comment: Got it! For some reason I thought you wanted to start only one instance of the application at first. Don't forget to unlock the file when you are done. Btw, since you need the lock to protect the file, you can put the fcntl lock directly on this file. However, you should keep in mind that closing *any* file descriptor associated with a file removes all the locks for this file that process has taken via any currently open file descriptor (from manpages for fcntl).

Answer (score 5):

The conventional UNIX way of doing this is with **PID files**.

Before a process starts, it checks to see if a pre-determined file - usually `/var/run/<process_name>.pid` exists. If found, its an indication that a process is already running and this process quits.

If the file does not exist, this is the first process to run. It creates the file `/var/run/<process_name>.pid` and writes its PID into it. The process unlinks the file on exit.

**Update:**

To handle cases where a daemon has crashed & left behind the pid file, additional checks can be made during startup if a pid file was found:

- Do a `ps` and ensure that a process with that PID doesn't exist
- If it exists ensure that its a different process

  - from the said `ps` output
  - from `/proc/$PID/stat`

Comment: This doesn't explain how to recover from a crashed process automatically. The file would still exist if a process exited abnormally.